# Jquery UI Autocomplete- How to format results AND add button at end?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've figured out how to change the formatting on my results:

https://github.com/salmanarshad2000/demos/blob/v1.0.4/jquery-ui-autocomplete/custom-html-in-dropdown.html

And I've figured out how I can add a link to the bottom of the results:

[Jquery Auto complete append link at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479498/jquery-auto-complete-append-link-at-the-bottom)

What I can't figure out is how to do both at the same time.

The closest that I've come is the following:

```
$( "#search1" ).autocomplete({
            source: products,
          minLength: 3,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
                event.preventDefault();
       },
       focus: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

        console.log(ul.content)
        var $div = $("<div></div>");

        $("<img style='height:76px;'>").attr("src", item.image).appendTo($div);
        $("<span></span>").text(item.label).appendTo($div);

        ($div).append( "<a href='https://google.com'>Click Me</a>" )

        return $("<li></li>").append($div).appendTo(ul);
            };
```

The problem is that adds the link to each individual returned result, rather than slamming it onto the end of the list.

I've tried various incarnations of wrapping the link (li, div, etc) but nothing's working.

What do I need to do to get a link as the last thing on the list?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spgbq6w7/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wur8vok9/23/

**HTML**

```
Search: <input id="search1">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var products = [{
    value: "MS-Word",
    label: "Microsoft Word 2013",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Microsoft_Word_2013_logo.svg"
  },
  {
    value: "MS-Excel",
    label: "Microsoft Excel 2013",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Microsoft_Excel_2013_logo.svg"
  },
  {
    value: "MS-Outlook",
    label: "Microsoft Outlook 2013",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Microsoft_Outlook_2013_logo.svg"
  },
  {
    value: "MS-PowerPoint",
    label: "Microsoft Word 2013",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Microsoft_PowerPoint_2013_logo.svg"
  },
  {
    value: "MS-Access",
    label: "Microsoft Access2013",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Microsoft_Access_2013_logo.svg"
  },
  {
    value: "Adobe-PSP",
    label: "Adobe Photoshop CC",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Adobe_Photoshop_CC_icon.svg"
  },
  {
    value: "Adobe-LR",
    label: "Adobe Lightroom CC",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Adobe_Photoshop_Lightroom_Classic_CC_icon.svg"
  },
  {
    value: "Adobe-PRM",
    label: "Adobe Premiere Pro CC",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Adobe_Premiere_Pro_CS6_Icon.png"
  },
  {
    value: "Adobe-ACR",
    label: "Adobe Acrobat",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Adobe_Acrobat_v8.0_icon.svg"
  },
  {
    value: "Adobe-ILS",
    label: "Adobe Illustrator CS6",
    image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Adobe_Illustrator_Icon_CS6.png"
  }
];

$(function() {
  $("#search1").autocomplete({
    source: products,
    minLength: 3,
    open: function() {
      var $li = $("<li>");
      var $link = $("<a>", {
        href: "#",
        class: "see-all"
      }).html("See All Results").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#search1").autocomplete("option", "minLength", 0);
        $("#search1").autocomplete("search", "");
      }).appendTo($li);
      $li.appendTo($('.ui-autocomplete'));
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#search1").autocomplete("option", "minLength", 3);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    console.log(ul.content)
    var $div = $("<div>").css("position", " relative");

    $("<img>", {
      src: item.image
    }).css("height", "38px").appendTo($div);
    $("<span>").css({
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      display: "inline-block",
      "margin-left": "3px"
    }).text(item.label).appendTo($div);

    return $("<li>").append($div).appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

So you're using `_renderItem()` properly. I removed the Link from here based on the example you linked to. I moved this to the `open` callback as is shown in the example. I also switched some of your code. It wasn't wrong, I just prefer this method.

So the items get rendered so that the image and label show as desired. The the `open` call back adds a final link item that causes the a search for all items. See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

> Can be called with an empty string and `minLength: 0` to display all items.

When an item is selected, the preferred `minLength` is returned to ensure that if the user starts a new search, it operates the same way it did the first time.

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wur8vok9/40/

Minor cleanup and better separation of code and style.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works, but I had to make a couple changes- the most significant was changing the "click" function here: }).html("See All Results").click(function(e) {

As you wrote it, it called the built-in search and showed more data-- what I really wanted was to open a new page with the search term.

I kept the e.preventDefault(); in there to override the basic handling, then used  window.location to get to the right page. It's not the cleanest thing ever, but it's working. Now to figure out why the background color won't change :)